# Make a new line in html table row from fetching in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to display image along with the text and from fetching from the database using php
here's the code

```
<table id = "menu-container" border = "2">
    <caption>Main Dish<caption>
    <tr>
    <?php
        if($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {                                   
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {                                               
    ?>                    
            <td class = "wrapword">

                <img src = "data:image/jpeg; base64 , <?php echo base64_encode($row['product_image']); ?>"
                height = "290" width = "350">
                <br>
                &nbsp;Name: <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>
                <br>
                &nbsp;Price: Php<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?> 
                <label id = "add-to-list">Add to list</label>

            </td>

    <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Menu Found";
        }
    ?> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

and here's the picture or the output of that code
i want to make a new line when the table row inside when table data has exceed the limit of 4 and the other data will go the bottom or make a new line is that possible? I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: May be this is a HTML markup problem. Could you show us the HTML result so we can help?

Comment: actually that's the only code in html i use. and sorry could you be more specific about what you mean of me showing the html result. so i don't misinterpret it thanks.

Comment: That's the .php file that is 'echoing' HTML code (sort of rendering the page). What I am asking is the result of that rendering, may be the whole table element copied from the chrome dev tools using: right click -> 'Inspect element' on the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically what Munawir was trying to get to. It has a simple counter which is checked if it is divisible by 4, without having a remainder. If it is, a new row is started. If not, stay on the current row.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {            
        $c = 0;                       
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // If it's not divisible by 4 without remainder - Same Row
            if(!($c % 4 == 0)){ 
                // echo <td> content
            } else {
                echo "</tr>"; //Close last row
                echo "<tr>"; //Open new row
                // echo <td> content
            }
            $c++;
        }
    } else {
        //...
    } ?>

    </tr> <!-- End last row -->
</table>
```

---

**Edit**

The solution could even be shortened to:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($c % 4 == 0){ 
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

    // echo <td> content

    $c++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need one variable where you will count how many items already collected. if that variable equals 4 in your case, you must empty gathering variable and collect again

```
<table id = "menu-container" border = "2">
    <caption>Main Dish<caption>

    <?php
    $html="";
    $i=1;
        if($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {                                   
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {                                               
                $html .= ' <td class = "wrapword">
                    <img src = "dat[![enter image description here][1]][1]a:image/jpeg; base64 , '.base64_encode($row['product_image']).'" height = "290" width = "350">
                    <br>
                    &nbsp;Name: '.$row['product_name'];.'<br>
                    &nbsp;Price: Php '.$row['product_price'].'<label id = "add-to-list">Add to list</label>

                </td>';

                if($i==4){
                    echo $html = '<tr>'.$html.'<tr>';
                    $html="";
                    $i=1;
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Menu Found";
        }
    ?> 
</table>
```

Comment: `$i` should be started as, and reset to `0`. Otherwise there will only be 3 results per row. Either that or change `if($i == 4)` to `if($i > 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table id = "menu-container" border = "2">
    <caption>Main Dish<caption>
    <tr>
    <?php
        if($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {            
            $i=0;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {        
    ?>                    
            <td class = "wrapword">

                <img src = "data:image/jpeg; base64 , <?php echo base64_encode($row['product_image']); ?>"
                height = "290" width = "350">
                <br>
                &nbsp;Name: <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>
                <br>
                &nbsp;Price: Php<?php echo $row['product_price']; ?> 
                <label id = "add-to-list">Add to list</label>

            </td>

    <?php
            $i++;
      if($i%4==0 && $i<$result->num_rows) echo '</tr><tr>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Menu Found";
        }
    ?> 
    </tr>
</table>
```